# Search bar e-commerce MERN stack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am following a video from udemy and making a website using MERN stack.

In the Video (Header.js)

```
<Route render={({ history }) => <Search history={history} />} />
```

I did the same but I had to wrap it inside of `Routes` because of the error

This is the App.js

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/search/:keyword" component={Home} />
  <Route path="/" element={<Search />} />
</Routes>
```

And Search.js

```
const Search = ({ history }) => {
  const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState('');

  const searchHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (keyword.trim()) {
      history.push(`/search/${keyword}`);
    } else {
      history.push('/');
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={searchHandler}>
      <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setKeyword(e.target.value)} />
      <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

In the video everything works,
but when I do this, the search bar disappears.

And if I follow chat GPT with codes like
removing the `component` and replacing it with `element`,
removing `history` from `header.js` code,
it shows the search bar, but says `history` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

`react-router-dom@6` removed the route props that existed in RRDv5. You should instead now use the React hooks. The `useNavigate` hook replaced the RRDv5 `useHistory` hook.

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const Search = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState('');

  const searchHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    navigate(keyword.trim() ? `/search/${keyword}` : "/");
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={searchHandler}>
      <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setKeyword(e.target.value)} />
      <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  );
};
```